# Unable to locate svg class using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to locate SVG class present in Angular APP having bar charts 
following is the html block

```
 <div class=" panel-body-style" _ngcontent-c1="">
   <table class="tabel bar-chart-table-fixed" _ngcontent-c1="">
     <tbody _ngcontent-c1="">
       <tr class="bar-chart-tr" _ngcontent-c1="">
         <td class="bar-label" _ngcontent-c1="">Assets ANR</td>
         <td id="bankwide-actual-chart" _ngcontent-c1="">
           <indium-charts _ngcontent-c1="" style="padding: 0px">
             <div id="holder" class="style-scope indium-charts">
               <svg class="bullet-bar-circle style-scope indium-charts" width="198" height="6.930000000000001">
             </div>
           </indium-charts>
         </td>
       </tr>
```

Please let me know how can we able to locate svg class in protractor

Comment: what solutions you have tried ?

Comment: @PrashanthSams : Havent got any solution yet

Comment: is the page viewable to us? incase can help you

Comment: No , it will not be viewable , it project internal , i just wanted to know how can find locator for SVG in chrome , the locator which works in fiirefox not working here , 1 point to not here the SVG is under shadow root

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was selenium have an issue to handle SVG tags.
You have to stick with only on cssSelector while dealing with SVG tags.

If you have only one id as holder then use below css selector

```
#holder > svg
```

For traverse to g and rect

```
#holder > svg > g > rect
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I am able to find SVG with $$("svg.bullet-bar-circle.style-scope.indium-charts") but i have g class inside it  <svg width="198"   height="6.930000000000001" class="bullet-bar-circle style-scope indium-charts"><g class="style-scope indium-charts"><rect class="bullet-bar-circle style-scope indium-charts" y="0" height="6.930000000000001" x="0" width="0"></rect><circle class="target-circle style-scope indium-charts" cx="0" cy="3.4650000000000003" r="3"></circle></g></svg>

Comment: @shubam : I am getting empty array in chrome however im mozilla it works perfectly

Comment: Try to put some wait brfore using this xpath.. First use Thread.sleep(10000); if it works then use Webdriver wait to fix the issue. Please accept the answer if solution works for you ..

Comment: i have wait already , the selector works fine with firefox but not with chrom , seems issue is diffrent