# Protractor: Not able to Reach an already exist element in DOM because it doesnt load all child elements

Tags: protractor, typescript2.0

If you look below snapshot, you will see that the Parent tag doesnt load all child elements in one go which is why my targeted element is not able to locate since it is present at the last.

Because of this I am not able to locate my element when i run the script because my element is present at the last of it. Please suggest what to do in this case. As far as i have understood is that I first have to expand these all nodes and then try to locate the element to click it. Please suggest.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxqgT.png)

[Second Image- Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6DxI.png)

Comment: Please do click on the Snapshot link to see the image.

Comment: is your application displays the list which you want or there is pagination when the list is displayed

Comment: I don't understand the question. What the problem to click "show all" button to show all the nodes in the DOM?

Comment: I have attached one snapshot with the details. Please click on the Second Image link to find it

Comment: may be you should wait till your node get load `browser.sleep(time);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not sure that this will work but you may try this

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)').then(function(){
       //whatever you need to check for here
    });
    element.all(by.tagName('g').filter(function(el,index){
       return el.isDisplayed();
    }).last().click();
```

you can click `.first()` or `.last()` element

Comment: I am getting this error on using "filter" : Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'By'. I am kind of a new to this tool so not able to fix  this.

Comment: can you tell which node exactly you want to select i mean `last()` `first()` or any other as your `id="g9721"`

Comment: I have attached one snapshot with the details. Please click on the Second Image link to find it

Comment: @ Rao, Any more suggestions what to do here?

Comment: @Tarun so in every g tag there is rectangle tag right

Comment: this may help you `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429627/unable-to-locate-svg-class-using-protractor`

Comment: and what error it shows when you try to click that elems